# Tying together arrays stored in DB to forms in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm a novice developer, some experience with rails but still have a lot to learn... I am developing a rails app that will have a form like the following:

select favorite colors:
[ ] red
[ ] blue
[ ] green

which will be stored in a table that looks like this:
ID
username
colors

So I am looking to store the array of colors into the colors column, and be able to go back and edit the record to adjust checkboxes. I'm not sure how to go about implementing this, thinking it would require some sort of form helper magic but then again maybe not.

Any guidance on how I could best achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: is the username tied to a user by any chance?

Comment: i also suggest that unless you were required to have that kind of table, to change it to more of an activerecord style where you have a table for colors and for users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty basic stuff. What you're looking for is a `has_one` relationship between a `User` and `Colors` model.

Actually, if it's checkboxes not radioboxes (user can select multiple colors), you need a `has_many` relationship.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association

and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

**EDIT**

A short and simple tutorial from Railscasts.com about a form helper gem, helped the idea of associations "click" in my mind. If you follow this 9 minute tutorial and think of substituting your `Color` model for the sample veterinary application's `Problem` model, you'll be well on your way.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/185-formtastic-part-2

Comment: The railscasts video you linked to nailed it, exactly the sort of thing I was after. Thanks for the info!